# use polipo to convert shadowsocks into an HTTP proxy

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, socks, polipo

My ssserver is started by docker image [oddrationale/docker-shadowsocks](https://github.com/oddrationale/docker-shadowsocks):

```
docker run -d -p 1984:1984 oddrationale/docker-shadowsocks -s 0.0.0.0 -p 1984 -k paaassswwword -m aes-256-cfb
```

Then I use `sslocal` command to get local proxy.

```
sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start --pid-file /data/tmp/sslocal.pid --log-file /data/tmp/sslocal.log
```

`/etc/shadowsocks.json` is like this:

```
{
  "server":"127.0.0.1",
  "server_port":1984,
  "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "local_port":1080,
  "password":"paaassswwword",
  "timeout":600,
  "method":"aes-256-cfb"
}
```

I use `polipo` to convert shadowsocks to http proxy, my `/etc/polipo/config` is:

```
proxyAddress = 0.0.0.0
socksProxyType = socks5
socksParentProxy = 127.0.0.1:1080
daemonise = true
pidFile = /data/tmp/polipo.pid
logFile = /data/tmp/polipo.log
```

I edit the iptables rules to make port 8123 can be accessed. I can access `http://host:8123` in browser, and the proxy looks work:

```
http_proxy=http://host:8123 curl -v google.com
```

the output is like this:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: google.com/
*   Trying host...
* Connected to host (host) port 8123 (#0)
> GET HTTP://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Length: 262
< Date: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 09:52:34 GMT
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Location: http://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=YkrvWPnOM-XLugTRgZDQBA
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=YkrvWPnOM-XLugTRgZDQBA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host host left intact
```

The command does not always run successfully, and sometimes I get the following error:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: google.com/
*   Trying host...
* Connected to host (host) port 8123 (#0)
> GET HTTP://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

The output of `netstat -tlnp` is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5067/python     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8123            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9704/polipo     
tcp6       0      0 :::8388                 :::*                    LISTEN      4238/docker-proxy
```

I really can't find the reason, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

google use https, not http, try

```
https_proxy=http://host:8123 curl -v https://www.google.com
```